How does one match the envelope recipient (not sender!) in a Sieve script if the receiving mail server is rewriting addresses?
The situation is that my mailbox receives spam to known spam addresses (a combination of a mailbox alias in the mail system and a recipient delimiter) that doesn’t has a correct To: header set. This means that the following Sieve script will not work:
# This doesn’t match anything since the spam doesn’t have the correct
# recipient address in the “To:” header
if address :all :is ["To"] ["alias-spamsuffix@altdomain.tld"] {
    discard;
    stop;
}

The standardized alternative would be to instead match the envelope recipient address, however in this case it also doesn’t work:
require ["envelope"];

# This doesn’t match since the MTA (Postfix) will rewrite
# “alias-spamsuffix@altdomain.tld” to “actual-spamsuffix@maindomain.tld”
# before passing the message to the LDA (Dovecot)
if envelope :all :is ["To"] ["alias-spamsuffix@altdomain.tld"] {
    discard;
    stop;
}

Instead one would have write the following that might end up accidentally match more than it should:
require ["envelope"];

# Works but matches everything for the mailbox with “-spamsuffix”
if envelope :all :is ["To"] ["actual-spamsuffix@maindomain.tld"] {
    discard;
    stop;
}

… using the Sieve subaddress achieves the exact same result.
My question therefore is: Is there any reliable way to read and match the envelope recipient address of the received message in such a setup at all?

While it is a bit hackish the best answer I found was to extract the recipient address from the 2nd Received header of the message: Since the first two Received headers are guaranteed to be generated locally be the receiving mail system (one by the MTA and one by the LDA) this should be safe unless Postfix completely changes the format.
Therefore the best answer to this question, as of 2024 when using Dovecot appears to be to do the following:
require ["index", "variables"];

# Extract envelope recipient from second “Received” header
#
# Uses the Sieve variables extension to create a convenient alias
# for the extracted recipient address and the Sieve index extension
# to ensure we only match on the “Received” header generated by the
# MTA.
if header :index 2 :matches ["Received"] "*<*>*" {
    set "rcpt_address" "${2}";
}

# Filter: Drop to Spam-only recipients (can list multiple here)
if string :is "${rcpt_address}" ["alias-spamsuffix@altdomain.tld"] {
    discard;
    stop;
}

# Filter: Alternate filter that notifies senders that their message has been dropped
if string :is "${rcpt_address}" ["otheralias@altdomain.tld"] {
    # Add URL where new address may be found
    if envelope :all :matches ["To"] "otheralias@altdomain.tld" {
        set "new_rcpt_src" "https://somedomain.tld/";
    } else {
        set "new_rcpt_src" "the website where you originally found this address again";
    }

    vacation
        :days 1
        :subject "Decommisioned e-mail address: ${rcpt_address}"
        "Unfortunately the e-mail address “${rcpt_address}” has been decommisioned due to spam. To find the current e-mail address please visit ${new_rcpt_src}!";
    discard;
    stop;
}

